# Algorithms For Finding Similar Images Across A Large Amount Of Images

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I know there are already some posts on this site to do with this question but none (as far as I can tell) tell me quite what I need to know.

I am interested in how image search engines (like Google images) run their image-based searching and so far I have found [this blog post](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html) which tells the user how to program out a fingerprinting function that will find similar images. The algorithm on this site only finds images that are either the same image but different resolution or the same image with a slight change to it. I'm looking for a way to put in an image, let's say an image of a forest, and it will give you other images of forests.

I am a beginner to this so I was hopefully looking for something detailed, not giving you the code to do it, just a guide to get me started. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I understand it, computer vision has not progressed to the point where you can feed it an image and it can draw general conclusions about the data (ex. "this is a picture of a forest"). Google can cheat because all of its images are on web pages. It can get a lot of clues from surrounding text, the alt attribute, etc. A truly general "similar image finder" would be very very hard to make.

Comment: Most of what the image search engines use for indexing is image metadata (text embedded inside the image file) and information from the page on which the image is found (the alt text of the image tag, for example, and surrounding text). Comparatively very little actual image processing is done.

Comment: That is not true: you can throw an image at Google with no other hints and it will return similar images. Extremely impressive is als ohttp://clarifai.com/ - which returns a number of tags for virtually any image. Fully based on image recognition. But this is certainly no trivial algorithm task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the common approach for image retrieval is actually inspired by text retrieval, so I will start by quickly reviewing text retrieval:

1. Each document is represented by its [bag-of-words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) model.
2. An [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), containing all the documents, is built.
3. When a user send a query `q`, the most similar documents of the database are returned, using the inverted index. The similarity between a document and the query `q` is often computed using the dot product of the two vectors representing the query and the document. (The [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) weighting is often used to build the vectors representing the documents.)

Image retrieval, as proposed by Sivic and Zisserman in [Video Google: A Text Retrieval Approach to Object Matching in Videos](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/publications/papers/sivic03.pdf), follows exactly the same approach. The only difference is the first step, where they define what is a "visual word", in order to have bag-of-words representation for images.

They start by extracting local features of the image such as [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform). Those local features (SIFT) are high dimensional vectors, and so, a clustering algorithm, such as [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), is applied to obtain `k` visual words: the `k` cluster centers are the "visual words". Then given an image, the local features (SIFT) are extracted and each one is assigned to the closest "visual word" or cluster center, thus obtaining a bag-of-words representation.

This method was later refined, see for example: [Hamming Embedding and Weak Geometric consistency for large-scale image search](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2008/JDS08/jegou_hewgc08.pdf) by Hervé Jégou, Matthijs Douze and Cordelia Schmid.

If you want to learn more on those methods, I strongly advise you to have a look at the material from the [Visual Recognition and Machine Learning
Summer School](http://www.rocq.inria.fr/cluster-willow/laptev/teaching/cvml2012/materials/index.html), in particular the slides for "instance-level recognition" and "large-scale visual search".

Code along [YouTube Video link](https://youtu.be/znM_Z_jYT8E) for this.